# Android: load images with zoom from URL

Tags: android, image, url, zooming

I am using to load my images with high resolution and zoom quality with the tutorial: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

It uses images from `Assets`. How I could do to load images from a `URL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class SubsamplingScaleImageView has also a method to load an image that isn't from Assets:

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView.setImageFile(String extFile)
```

So you can get the image from the URL and save it on internal storage. Then you can load the image using the path from internal storage.
To get the image as a Bitmap from an URL:

```
URL myFileUrl = new URL (StringURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

To save the Bitmap on internal storage:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(context.getCacheDir() + filename);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
// Don't forget to add a finally clause to close the stream
```

Finally

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView =  (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageFile(context.getCacheDir() + filename);
```

Comment: The error is because you are connecting to the network from the main thread. You have to use that code in an AsyncTask

Comment: I don't understand your answer... I don't know what to put in doInBackground, onpostexecute...

Comment: You have to put the two first blocks of code in the doInBackground method. Then in the onPostExecute you have to call a method of your activity in which you add the third block of code. If you don't know how to use an AsyncTask, that is not part of this question. You can check this tutorial instead: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by creating a Bitmap from the provided URL string extra, although I think this may defeat the purpose of SubsamplingScaleImageView because I'm loading the entire Bitmap.

```
private void locateImageView() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    if (bundle.getString("imageUrl") != null) {
        String imageUrl = bundle.getString("imageUrl");
        Log.w(getClass().toString(), imageUrl);

        imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        URL newUrl = new URL(imageUrl);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            imageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(myBitmap));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            Log.w(getClass().toString(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

}